# Convert timeval to time_t

Tags: c

How do I convert timeval to time_t?  I'm trying to convert:
umtp->ut_tv to a time_t so I can use a difftime(a,b).

```
struct {
   int32_t tv_sec;         /* Seconds */
   int32_t tv_usec;        /* Microseconds */
           } ut_tv;                    /* Time entry was made */
 struct timeval ut_tv;      /* Time entry was made */
```

Comment: Are you sure the microseconds don't matter to you?  If they do, then you need to write your own `struct timeval difftimeval(const struct timeval *t1, const struct timeval *t2);` function that returns `t2 - t1`.  Or you can define the return type to be a `double` if you prefer, so it is more nearly plug-compatible with `difftime()`.

Comment: Incidentally, the code shown won't compile; you define a variable `ut_tv` twice with two different types (as an anonymous struct and as a `struct timeval`).

Comment: Where did you get this definition of `timeval`? The type of `tv_sec` is supposed to be `time_t` and there is no conversion to be done, only truncation.

Comment: @R this is coming from utmp.h which is part of Linux.  @Jonathan, you're right about declared twice, in utmp.h, I actually took out an else statement so it's really one or the other.  I was able to just use (time_t) utmp->ut_tv.tv.sec

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`time_t` just stores seconds, so

```
 time_t time = (time_t)ut_tv.tv_sec;
```

Should work, but since you're just looking for a difference, there's always the magic of *subtraction*.

```
struct timeval diff = {a.tv_sec-b.tv_sec, a.tv_usec-b.tv_usec};
```

This lets you keep all the precision you had before.

Comment: I was using "->" instead of "." before ".tv_sec"

Comment: The subtraction is not properly normalized; if `a.tv_usec = 123456` and `b.tv_usec = 654321`, then you end up with a negative fractional time, which should be normalized to a positive value and the `tv_sec` component adjusted appropriately.  Of course, if `a` comes before `b`, maybe both parts of the result should be negative?  This is 'segmented arithmetic', and it is typically easiest to keep the sign in a separate field.  Where there isn't a separate sign field, then both value segments should have the same sign (or one or the other can be zero).

Comment: I would say all but the most-significant field should always be non-negative.

Comment: @R..: that works fine until you print out a negative value.  Printing `-1.900000` when you mean `-0.100000` is the sort of thing that gives users the heebie-jeebies. Or, at least, at the point of printing out, you have to normalize the numbers. Of course, you have to do that, regardless; amongst other things, you must print the fractional part with `%06d` or `%.6d`, and make sure it is positive; again, if you omit the width specification, you can mislead people by printing 1 µs as `0.1`, which is also not good!.  Handling signed segmented numbers w/o a sign bit requires non-negligible effort.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you both wrong. the time value calculates as (double)(t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000 + (double)(t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000, so it never goes negative nor tv_usec diff whatever value it takes will never be above the decimal point, and tv_sec diff never can be below decimal point. overall, time is just two digits - sec, msec: "0.0" that is why ts_usec being introduced - and never being used alone. to calculate time diff, you have to convert to either secs or  msecs and then subtract, then you always get the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

Without using c-cast, you can simply do this :

```
struct timeval rawtime_s_us;
gettimeofday( &rawtime_s_us, NULL );
time_t rawtime_s = rawtime_s_us.tv_sec;
```