# How to convert timeval and time_t?

Tags: c, linux

How do I convert timeval to time_t? I'm trying to convert:

```
struct timeval tv;
time_t tm;
tm = (time_t)tv;
```

This is it?

Comment: No, that's not it. [Convert timeval to time\_t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252849/convert-timeval-to-time-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition (from *man gettimeofday*)

```
struct timeval {
           time_t      tv_sec;     /* seconds */
           suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
};
```

So you'd need to do

```
tm=tv.tv_sec;
```

Answer (score 1):

timeval is defined as:

```
struct timeval {
    time_t      tv_sec;  // seconds
    suseconds_t tv_usec; // and microseconds
};
```

And time_t is defined as:

```
typedef long time_t;
```

The timeval structure is used to specify a time interval but the time_t is used to specify a time (the number of seconds since the Epoch). If you insist to convert it, you'll need to pick the tv_sec of a timeval:

```
tm = tv.tv_sec;
```