# Accurate Time Keeping in C with High Resolution

Tags: c, time, real-time

First off I know there are a lot of similar questions and I have done a lot of digging please refrain from immediate hostility ( in my experience the people on this site are pretty hostile if they believe a question has already been asked answered) until you hear me out. If the answer is out there I haven't found it and I don't want to hijack another persons question.

That being said I am working in C on a linux based microcomputer. I have been using it to track and control motor RPM which obviously requires good time keeping. I was originally using calculations with the processor clock to track time on the order of milliseconds but for a variety of reasons that are probably woefully apparent this was problematic. I then switched over to using time.h and specifically the difftime() function. This was a good solution which allows me to accurately track and control the motors RPM with little to no issue. However I want to now plot that data. This again was not overly problematic except that the plot looks terrible because my time scale can not go any lower than seconds.

The best solution I could find would be to use sys/time.h and gettimeofday() which can give time since the epoch in greater resolution. However the issue is, as far as I can tell, that there is no difftime() type function for this that will maintain the higher time resolution. Why is this an issue? Because difftime() returns a double value that can easily be used to calculate RPM from a rotary encoder rotation count (rotations/(sec/60)) whereas there doesn't seem to be a way to do this with gettimeofday() as one uses time_t structs and the other uses timeval structs.

So is there a way to accurately return time differences between two times (as determined by real time elapsed since the epoch) with a better resolution than seconds? Or alternatively does anyone know of a better approach to accurately gauging elapsed time to calculate RPM? Thank you.

Comment: how about converting time_t to timeval structs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252849/convert-timeval-to-time-t

Comment: Without hard real-time extensions, my very serious advice is **not to do**. Depending on what exactly you are doing and what kind of motor this is, it will not work, break your motor or (if that is a high-voltage/high current motor) risk lives.

Comment: @Olaf if he runs risks or not depends much on the interface semantics and hardware he uses. Without knowing what he actually does, it is kind of pointless to theorize. The mere fact that he uses difftime suggests to me that he might run an endless loop without blocking ever. This would rather be an addressable problem. epoll to the rescue?

Comment: @Olaf it is a tiny little motor coupled to another tiny little motor for learning purposes only. PID feedback control system. It works. The ONLY issue I have is that I want to plot the data to show how RPM v. Time and have  it look smooth. Which seems to be impossible since RPM calculation uses seconds and time is restricted to seconds.

Comment: @J.Hamman I still have to figure out how the plotting comes into all of this. You can do a queue and add your (x,y) values into the queue, then plot in another thread, can you not?

Comment: When you say "microcomputer" do you mean a PC or a microcontroller? The resolution of the system's timer is completely dependent on the hardware, not the OS. Microcontrollers are better for sensitive time keeping because they are designed for tasks like motor control. PC's are lousy at sensitive time keeping because they are designed to do much more complicated tasks.

Comment: You wrote "I have been using it to track and **control** motor RPM" (emphasis mine). The term "control" (here) implies some kind of regulation loop. This requires precise timing with a resolution and jitter sufficient for the intended regulation quality and as high as possible/reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the result of `gettimeofday` to a double:

```
gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
double dsecs = now.tv_sec + (now.tv_usec / 1000000.0);
```

Then your `difftime` is just a subtraction of two of these `dsecs`